# How to set a css class of the widget type with Symfony2

Tags: css, symfony, widget, twig

Is there a way to apply a specific class on the root div of an input depending on the input type ?

ex.:

```
<div class="radio-input">
    <input...
    ....
</div>
```

I tried to overload "fields.html.twig" with this :

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    <div class="{{ type }}-input">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

But "type" is always equal to "text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a particularly nice solution but it seems `block_prefixes` is passed to block `form_row`.  Block_prefixes is an array of the form field types in order of inheritance so a text field called first name would have a block_prefixes array like:

`block_prefixes = array("form","field","text","first_name")`

Which means you could potentially get the second from last array element and use that:

```
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="{{ (block_prefixes|slice((block_prefixes|length - 2),1))|first }}-input">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

I'm sure there is a nicer way than this though I just don't have it to mind.

P.s type is undefined which is why its always `text` for you as you are setting it to default to text